# GenericClass doesn't support Class<float>

Tags: android, kotlin, scichart

I am integrating scichart to my android project and facing this error. I need to display ohlc data so, base on this tutorial https://www.scichart.com/example/android-candlestick-chart-example/ I wrote

```
val dataSeries = OhlcDataSeries(Date::class.java, Double::class.java)
```

That was translated from java code

```
IOhlcDataSeries<Date, Double> dataSeries = new OhlcDataSeries<>(Date.class, Double.class);
```

I got this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.qh.cointracker, PID: 5275
  java.util.NoSuchElementException: GenericClass doesn't support Class<double>
   at com.scichart.data.numerics.math.GenericMathFactory.create(GenericMathFactory.java:65)
   at com.scichart.charting.model.dataSeries.DataSeries.<init>(DataSeries.java:91)
   at com.scichart.charting.model.dataSeries.XDataSeries.<init>(XDataSeries.java:58)
   at com.scichart.charting.model.dataSeries.OhlcDataSeries.<init>(OhlcDataSeries.java:58)
   at com.scichart.charting.model.dataSeries.OhlcDataSeries.<init>(OhlcDataSeries.java:73)
   at com.qh.cointracker.activities.fragments.SymbolChartFragment.initExample(SymbolChartFragment.kt:57)
   at com.qh.cointracker.activities.fragments.SymbolChartFragment.onViewCreated(SymbolChartFragment.kt:37)
```

Can someone give me any idea to solve this error

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your code is working with the corresponding primitive type. You can use the following property defined on `KClass` instead:

```
/**
 * Returns a Java [Class] instance corresponding to the given [KClass] instance.
 * In case of primitive types it returns corresponding wrapper classes.
 */
public val <T : Any> KClass<T>.javaObjectType: Class<T>
```

As the KDoc describes, the corresponding wrapper type will be returned:

```
Double::class.javaObjectType //class java.lang.Double
```

Answer (score 3):

I know its already answered, but for future reference:

There are examples of using [SciChart Android Charts with Kotlin](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Android.Examples) on their public github page. Under the v2.x -> Showcase folder

The [EcgViewModel.kt](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Android.Examples/blob/master/v2.x/Showcase/app/src/main/kotlin/com/scichart/scishowcase/viewModels/ecg/EcgViewModel.kt) shows how to create and fill XyDataSeries

The [StockChartViewModel.kt](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Android.Examples/blob/master/v2.x/Showcase/app/src/main/kotlin/com/scichart/scishowcase/viewModels/trader/StockChartViewModel.kt) shows how to create and fill OhlcDataSeries

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that doing `Double::class.java` actually gets the primitive type `double` and not the boxed type `Double`.  This seems clear when looking at the stack trace and seeing the lower case `d` in `Class<double>`.  Try just using `Double::class` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `Double::class` is not buildable. It should be `Double::class.javaObjectType`

Comment: Thanks, `Double::class.javaObjectType` works for me - no more crash. Interesting that SciCharts had Kotlin examples in v2.x but in V4 everything has regressed to Java only. Seems a bit strange.